# How to create a Spark Streaming jar that would work in AWS EMR?

Tags: eclipse, scala, amazon-web-services, sbt, apache-spark

I've been developing a [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/streaming/) application with Eclipse, and I'm using sbt to run it locally.

Now I want to deploy the application on AWS using a jar, but when I try to use the command `package` of sbt it creates a jar without all dependencies so when I upload it on AWS it won't work because of Scala being missing.

Is there a way to create a uber-jar with SBT? Am I doing something wrong with the deployment of Spark on AWS?

Comment: Have you checked [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) ?

Comment: I'm doing it right now, but it keeps giving me problems with deduplicate error during merging phase.

Comment: You might want to check the technical article about running Spark on Elastic MapRedcue service - https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/4926593393724923

Comment: I read that article but it doesn't say anything on how upload and launch my application, it just saw how to launch an example.

Answer (score 2):

For creating uber-jar with sbt, use sbt plugin sbt-assembly. For more details about creating uber-jar using sbt-assembly refer [the blog post](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/)

After creating you can run the assembly jar using java -jar command.

But from Spark-1.0.0 onwards the spark-submit script in Spark’s bin directory is used to launch applications on a cluster [for more details refer here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Yes I read that, I've also read all the documentation about the new version that came out yesterday. The problem is, as you can see from my question title, I want to make it run on AWS EMR and not any cluster. 
I know that Spark includes scripts to start and work with a EC2 cluster, but that's not what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be following [Running Spark on EC2](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) that reads:

> The spark-ec2 script, located in Spark’s ec2 directory, allows you to
>   launch, manage and shut down Spark clusters on Amazon EC2. It
>   automatically sets up Spark, Shark and HDFS on the cluster for you.
>   This guide describes how to use spark-ec2 to launch clusters, how to
>   run jobs on them, and how to shut them down. It assumes you’ve already
>   signed up for an EC2 account on the Amazon Web Services site.

I've only partially followed the document so I can't comment on how well it's written.

Moreover, according to [Shipping Code to the Cluster](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) chapter in the other document:

> The recommended way to ship your code to the cluster is to pass it
>   through SparkContext’s constructor, which takes a list of JAR files
>   (Java/Scala) or .egg and .zip libraries (Python) to disseminate to
>   worker nodes. You can also dynamically add new files to be sent to
>   executors with SparkContext.addJar and addFile.

Comment: "The recommended way to ship your code to the cluster is to pass it through SparkContext’s constructor"
So how do I create that jar? And how should I pass it through a SparkContext?
Anyway my plan is to make it run on EMR and not on EC2